# How to get call relations of an open solution by using a plugin

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsx, vspackage, visual-studio-sdk, call-hierarchy

I try to develop a VSPackage for VS 2010 that investigates all the available methods in the current solution and to reconstruct the call relations of each single method just like the built in Call Hierarchy feature of VS does.

I managed to get all the available names of the types and its members in the solution by using the DTE automation object by going down from the solution to its projects, the projects classes/types and the classes members (most importantly its methods), however I’m not able to reconstruct the call relations. I did not find any service of VS/VS SDK that could provide me some help. Any hints?

Thanks in advance!